# How to mock a class methods when called inside another class using Spock framework

Tags: java, groovy, spock, spring-boot-test

```
public class BookService {

    public BookService() {
    }

    public List<Book> listAvailableBooks() {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Book book1 = new Book("The Color of Magic", "T. P.", true);
        Book book2 = new Book("There and Back Again", "B. B.", true);
        Book book3 = new Book("Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", "P. K. D.", false);
        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);
        books.add(book3);
        return books;
    }
}
```

BookService is instantiated inside WorkService class. How do I mock this class's method, so it always returns 0.

```
listAvailableBooks(); //should always return 0;
```

WorkService Class:

```
public class WorkService {

    public Integer listSize(){
        BookService bs = new BookService();
        return bs.listAvailableBooks().size();
    }
}
```

And finally, this is my spock groovy test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class BookServiceTests extends Specification {

    //BookService bookService
    WorkService workService = new WorkService()
    BookService bookService

    def "returns no books if no books available"() {
        given: "no books"
        bookService = Stub()

        when: "retrieving available books"
        bookService.listAvailableBooks() >> new ArrayList<Book>()

        then: "there are no books available"
        workService.listSize() == 0//expecting 0, but returning 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the `BookService` in as a parameter for the constructor of `WorkService`.  Then you can mock it under test

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. But I'm writing integration tests and this is a POC of the original code and I can't change the code.

Comment: Looks like you can't then, untestable code is untestable

Comment: Well, to be fair, in this example, you could just test that `BookService. listAvailableBooks()` works as expected as the method under test just returns the `size()` which I assume is tested by Oracle ;-)  I suspect your actual case is more complex than the example though :-(

Comment: True that. I'm writing integration test cases and this is a POC for the original test case.

Comment: Maybe a full end to end integration test then? Stand up a database, add a known number of books, and test that the result of the call is the expected number?

Comment: You can try `BookService bookService = GroovyMock(BookService, global: true); bookService.listAvailableBooks() >> []; new BookService() >> { bookService }`

Comment: @HardikModha this only works if the `BookService` itself is a Groovy class.

Comment: Umm, I don't think it's 100% true. I've used `GroovyMock` in the past to mock the instantiation where the class to be mocked was Java class.

Comment: Do you really have 3 hard coded books in the original BookService? If so, why you try to test impossible case: return empty book list?

Comment: @DmytroMaslenko, I'm looking for possibilities to mock the service. In case of a mock, like in mockito, I can make it return 0, even though there are 3 books in the book service.

Comment: Sorry for yet another comment, but I just found this question and this comment: "I'm writing integration tests (...) can't change the code." Sorry man, maybe someone in your dev team does not understand what test automation is all about. One of many reasons to do it is to uncover design flaws in the code such as bad testability due to missing dependency injection. The code instantiates its dependency by itself and is an urgent candidate for refactoring. The code is the problem, not the test. So stop trying to do test wizardry but instead make the devs **refactor the friggin' code!**